# how to remove some characters in string in R

Tags: r, string

I analyse some gene id. these Ids similar as follow:

"ENSG00000189001.9"  "ENSG00000179152.17" "ENSG00000131374.13"

1- I would like to remove '.' and every character after that such as follow:

"ENSG00000189001"  "ENSG00000179152" "ENSG00000131374"

2-After step1, I would like to remove "" from my string such as below:

ENSG00000189001  ENSG00000179152  ENSG00000131374

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `gsub`

```
GID = c("ENSG00000189001.9", "ENSG00000179152.17", "ENSG00000131374.13")
GID2 = gsub("\\..*", "", GID)
cat(GID2, "\n")
ENSG00000189001 ENSG00000179152 ENSG00000131374
```

Note that if you just type GID2, you will still see the quotes.  That is just how R indicates that these are strings.  Using cat shows only the string contents

A little detail about the regular expression:
`\\.`  matches the first period found in each string.
`.*` matches everything after that.
`gsub` will replace the matched part (period and everything after) with "", i.e. the empty string.

Comment: Thanks. As your comment, I found that "\\..*" is regular expression. how can i find these regular expressions in R for future?

Comment: You can get a little help just by typing `help(regex)`. But that is rather terse. You can find a lot of help by Googling `r regex tutorial`.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few fun, out of the ordinary ways to get the desired result.

```
scan(text=GID, what="", comment.char=".")
# Read 3 items
# [1] "ENSG00000189001" "ENSG00000179152" "ENSG00000131374"
dirname(chartr(".", "/", GID))
# [1] "ENSG00000189001" "ENSG00000179152" "ENSG00000131374"
read.table(text=GID, sep=".", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)$V1
# [1] "ENSG00000189001" "ENSG00000179152" "ENSG00000131374"
stringi::stri_split_fixed(GID, ".", simplify=TRUE)[,1]
# [1] "ENSG00000189001" "ENSG00000179152" "ENSG00000131374"
```

Data:

```
GID <- c("ENSG00000189001.9", "ENSG00000179152.17", "ENSG00000131374.13")
```